# Why F# for loop applied to a 2D (not jagged) array yields obj type?

Tags: f#

```
let A = array2D [[1;2;3];[4;5;6]]
```

Then `A` is `int [,]` type.

Next,

```
let B = [for i in A do yield i]
```

Then `B` is `obj list` type, not `int list` type.
I want an `int`-typed list.

Why is it?